# Find int-type from a file and calculate sum _ C++

Tags: c++

C++
Give a text file consisting of digits and letters, your task is to find the int-type numbers from the file and calculates their sum.
I tried to use

```
while (!file.eof()) {
file >> x; /// declared x as int
sum += x;
}
```

but it was an infinite loop.
How can I do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Who teaches `while (!file.eof())`?

Comment: Don't remember, probably it is possible to set letters as file stream separators instead of spaces, but it is possible to implemente whole parsing from scratch, like I just did [in following code](https://godbolt.org/z/aM8T5PYz1) for you, please put a look. Very first small block of code writes example text into file, this block is not needed if you have already existing file, remove this block.